# Use Taylor sequence write approximate value

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Use Taylor sequence write approximate value:

$$ \sqrt{9.5} $$

Estimate the error approximations three components. Which function should I  expand?

Comment: $\sqrt{10-x}$, or $\sqrt{9+x}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to expand $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ about $x=9$. For that you will want to express $\sqrt{x}$ in the form $a_0+a_1(x-9)+a_2(x-9)^2+\cdots$.

Alternately (and this would be my preference) expand $f(x)=\sqrt{9+x}=(9+x)^{1/2}$ about $x=0$, that is, find (part of) the Maclaurin expansion of $(9+x)^{1/2}$.

The two ways are essentially equivalent. In the first version, you will put $x=9.5$. In the second, you will put $x=0.5$.

**Remark:** One might think in terms of using $f(x)=\sqrt{10+x}$. The disadvantage  is that then the coefficients involve $\sqrt{10}$. If we use $\sqrt{9+x}$, the coefficients are nice rational numbers.

I also direct you to an equivalent but more attractive version of the second way suggested by @minar. It uses $f(x)=3(1+x)^{1/2}$ at $x=\frac{1}{18}$

Comment: It might be simpler to write $\sqrt{9+1/2}=3\sqrt{1+1/18}$ and then expand around $1$. In many courses, the expansion of $\sqrt{\,}$ around $1$ is part of the basic examples.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. I used the "uglier" (but equivalent) version because it matches up more nicely with expanding $\sqrt{x}$ about $9$.